# Upload issue in Codeigniter with image and text/numbers

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

First of all sorry for the long post with code, but i feel like i need to explain myself straight. The issue is, i'm trying to insert some data into a database and also the file name in the RESTAURANT_IMAGE column. Everything inserts perfectly fine but the image doesn't upload and the file name is not inserted into the database.

EDIT: Edited the callback function to properly return True or False and now i do the insert in the main function if the callback returns true.
Now i am able to upload the image successfully but still dont get the file name and extension to put into my database.

```
    function restaurant_add()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $config = array(
                                        array(
                                         'field'   => 'RestaurantName',
                                         'label'   => 'Restaurant Name',
                                         'rules'   => 'required|callback_restaurant_check'
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                         'field'   => 'RestaurantAddress',
                                         'label'   => 'Address',
                                         'rules'   => 'required'
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                         'field'   => 'RestaurantReservations',
                                         'label'   => 'Reservations',
                                         'rules'   => 'max_length[1]|integer'
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                         'field'   => 'RestaurantWifi',
                                         'label'   => 'RestaurantWifi',
                                         'rules'   => 'max_length[1]|integer'
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                            'field'   => 'RestaurantDelivery',
                                            'label'   => 'Restaurant Delivery',
                                            'rules'   => 'max_length[1]|integer'
                                         ),
                                        array(
                                            'field'   => 'RestaurantMultibanco',
                                            'label'   => 'RestaurantMultibanco',
                                            'rules'   => 'max_length[1]|integer'
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                                'field'   => 'RestaurantImage',
                                                'label'   => 'RestaurantImage',
                                                'rules'   => ''
                                                 )
                                        );

            $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->load->view('sample_navbar_view');
                $this->load->view('restaurant_add');
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
            $file_name = $this->do_upload();
                $data = array(
     'RESTAURANT_NAME' => $this->input->post('RestaurantName'),
     'RESTAURANT_ADDRESS' => $this->input->  post('RestaurantAddress'),
     'RESTAURANT_RESERVATIONS'=> $this->input->  post('RestaurantReservations'),
     'RESTAURANT_WIFI'=> $this->input->  post('RestaurantWifi'),
     'RESTAURANT_DELIVERY'=> $this->input->  post('RestaurantDelivery'),
     'RESTAURANT_MULTIBANCO'=> $this->input->    post('RestaurantMultibanco'),
     'RESTAURANT_OUTDOOR_SEATING'=> $this->input->   post('RestaurantOutdoorSeating'),
     'RESTAURANT_IMAGE'=> $file_name
);
        $this->load->model('restaurant_model');
       $this->restaurant_model->restaurant_add($data);

                return TRUE;
            }
}
```

Callback function to check if the restaurant name exists, if it does, it doesn't register it, if it doesn't sends the data into the model.

```
function restaurant_check($restaurantname){
    $this->load->model('restaurant_model');
    $result = $this->restaurant_model->check_restaurant_name($restaurantname);

    if($result > 0) {
        return FALSE;
}
    else    {
            return TRUE;
        }
 }
```

I used the upload file article present in the [Codeigniter Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

View Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<?php echo form_open_multipart('restaurant/restaurant_add');?>
<form name="restaurant_add" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url().'Restaurant/restaurant_add'; ?>">
<h2>Register your Restaurant</h2>
<input class="form-control" type="text" class="user" name="RestaurantName"      placeholder="Restaurant Name">
<input class="form-control"type="text" class="pass" name="RestaurantAddress" placeholder="Restaurant Address">
<input class="form-control"type="number" class="numero" name="RestaurantReservations" placeholder="Restaurant Rerservations">
  <input class="form-control"type="number" class="numero" name="RestaurantWifi" placeholder="Wi-Fi">
  <input class="form-control"type="number" class="numero" name="RestaurantDelivery" placeholder="Home Deliveries">
  <input class="form-control"type="number" class="numero" name="RestaurantMultibanco" placeholder="Have Multibanco?">
    <input class="form-control"type="number" class="numero" name="RestaurantOutdoorSeating" placeholder="Esplanada">
  <input class="form-control"type="file" class="image" name="RestaurantImage" placeholder="Upload a Picture">
<div class="container">
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-danger"type="submit">Registar</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Model Code:

```
     function restaurant_add($info)
{
  $query =
                "INSERT INTO RESTAURANTS
                (RESTAURANT_NAME,RESTAURANT_ADDRESS,RESTAURANT_RESERVATIONS,
        RESTAURANT_WIFI,RESTAURANT_DELIVERY,RESTAURANT_MULTIBANCO,
        RESTAURANT_OUTDOOR_SEATING,RESTAURANT_IMAGE
        )
                VALUES
                (
        '".$info['RESTAURANT_NAME']."',
                    '".$info['RESTAURANT_ADDRESS']."',
        '".$info['RESTAURANT_RESERVATIONS']."',
        '".$info['RESTAURANT_WIFI']."',
        '".$info['RESTAURANT_DELIVERY']."',
        '".$info['RESTAURANT_MULTIBANCO']."',
        '".$info['RESTAURANT_OUTDOOR_SEATING']."',
        '".$info['RESTAURANT_IMAGE']."'
                )
                ";
            $result =   $this->db->query($query);
          return TRUE;

}

function check_restaurant_name($restaurantname)    {
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    $query = "SELECT RESTAURANT_NAME FROM RESTAURANTS WHERE RESTAURANT_NAME = '".$restaurantname."'";

    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $rows = $result->num_rows();
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }
    else
    {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
    }
return $rows;
}
```

do_upload() function:

```
    public function do_upload()
 {
             $config['upload_path']          = './assets/images/restaurantes';
             $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
             $config['max_size']             = 2000;
             $config['max_width']            = 1024;
             $config['max_height']           = 768;

             $this->load->library('upload', $config);

             if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
             {
                             $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                             $this->load->view('success_view', $error);
             }
             else
             {
                             $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                             $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
             }
             $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            //Returns array of containing all of the data related to the file you uploaded.
                            $file_name =  $this->upload->file_name;
    return $file_name;
}
```

Comment: Hello mate!
First, when you called restaurant_check you can't male a redirect (you only return true/false in callbacks) or make an exit(). Then I can see your code where you are making an insert and upload the image. Can you paste that codes please?

Comment: Edited with the model code.
I try to upload the image with the first line of restaurant_check function, also after i called it i expect the return result to pass over the file name to insert it into the database. Thanks for answering !

Comment: Ohh wait.. Why are you inserting the info when the validation hasn't finished. I can't see your upload code. When you use a call back you only can RETURN true or false.

Comment: I use the callback function to check if the Restaurant name exists or not in the database, can i do that?

Comment: Added the upload function. Also i edited the main code functions according to the call back norm, and now i just check if the name is there or not in the callback function. @elddenmedio

Comment: Hi, now your callback restaurant_check is ok now, now dou you continue having with some problems with the validation, insert and upload? @Ribeiro

Comment: That is all fine, it uploads but I can't get the $file_name to pass through to the function that called it

Comment: In your method do_upload you need to return $this->upload->file_name, thats all

Comment: It works now, thank you @elddenmedio !

Will update with the proper solution!